# loop through BeautifulSoup bs4.element.ResultSet

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I encounter an error I can't seem to solve...

Just for context it goes about extracting data of real estate properties sales :-)
Each of the tables I'm looking into contains data about the property, like the date of sale, location, the nb bedrooms, the price etc.

```
url = "https://www.immoweb.be/fr/annonce/9309298"
property_data = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

property_tables = property_data.find_all("tr", class_="classified-table__row")
```

This results in a `bs4.element.ResultSet` object as follows:

```
property_tables = [
<tr class="classified-table__row">
    <th class="classified-table__header" scope="row">À partir de</th>
    <td class="classified-table__data">Immédiatement</td>
</tr>,

<tr class="classified-table__row">
    <th class="classified-table__header" scope="row"> Disponible le </th>
    <td class="classified-table__data"> 1 janvier 2021 - 00:00</td>
</tr>,

<tr class="classified-table__row">
    <th class="classified-table__header" scope="row">Quartier ou lieu-dit</th>
    <td class="classified-table__data">Groot-Halle</td>
</tr>
 ....]
```

I would like to loop though this `bs4.element.ResultSet` object to extract each field of the table into a dictionnary.
Hence for this example, I would like to have an output as follows:

```
dictionnary = {"A partir de":"Immédiatement", "Disponible le": "1 Janvier 2021", "Quartier ou lieu-dit":"Groot-Halle"}
```

My current code is:

```
dictionnary= {}

for table in property_tables:
    key = table.find('th').string.strip()
    value = table.find('td').string.strip()
    dictionnary[key] = value
```

but I get an `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'`

However when I used the code outside of the loop on the first element of the list (hence using find() instead of find_all() ), it worked...

Comment: Your `property_tables` list is all messed up. It's not wrapped around quotations...

Comment: but this is how beautifulsoup does the data extraction. I did: `property_data = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url_test).content, 'html.parser')`, then `property_tables = property_data.find_all("tr", class_="classified-table__row")`

Comment: Which parser are you using?

Comment: The url isn't a string either? Was that a pasting mistake?

Comment: yes parsing mistake, sorry

Comment: Is this now resolved?

Comment: OH! I think I spotted the mistake. So, I have the error :  `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'`. Could it be because one of the `<td class="classified-table__data">` is actually not made of text/string but is an `<a>` tag, hence a hyperlink?!